# Transparencies of text boxes change in print?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production

I'm designing a magazine intended to be printed for publication. On InDesign, I have set the transparency/opacity as it best looks on screen. This is for textboxes and background overlays. But I've heard that this usually doesn't stay the same in print (gets usually darker).

Is it true? Is there something that should be taken care of? Is there some sort of a definitive print preview?

PS. We do not have a budget enough to do multiple print reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, transparencies do tend to get a little darker when printed. Unfortunately there isn't really a solution to this except getting a print review since there are multiple variables in the print process that could contribute to this phenomena. I would suggest going with what looks best and then lighten it up a bit, so long as lightening it will not cause visibility issues. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

A few things I do:

- export the job as a cmyk tiff and see what it looks like
- ask for a printers proof
- go to the printers and press pass the job